# Sikuli4Net is giving me an error on C# selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, sikuli

I was trying to implement image based verification on my selenium project with the help on Sikuli4Net.
After following some tutorials I'm getting an error as below.

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

This is my code.

```c#
APILauncher launch = new APILauncher(false);
Pattern Image1 = new Pattern(@"C\Users\XXX\Pictures\google.png");
launch.Start();
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver1\");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
Screen scr = new Screen();
```

The exception will occurred at the 3rd line where it starts the

> API Launcher

.
So is there any solution for above error or is there any better alternatives to image based element identifications on selenium c#.

Comment: try by providing url protocol with `https` like `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: No not even reaching to that line, Exception occurred at 3rd line.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904963/6793637 u tried this ?